# Circular linked-list "derails" unexpectedly

Tags: c++, memory, linked-list, memory-address, singly-linked-list

Usually I land here on Stack Overflow by searching for solutions to some silly questions about C/C++ programming, but this time it's not about a missing ";" or a one-short char array.

It's about a simple concept: linked lists.
But in a circular form: a->b->c->d->e->f->a->b->....
As simple as that.

Except something really weird happens.
Let me explain.

What I do is translate characters in bits, but "character bits": I calculate binary of char decimal values and then write each single 1 and 0 in a node of a linked list.
Since I need to read this list in a circular, borderless way, I built it like a ring, which means the last "->next" contains the address of the first item.
Then, through a very simple function called "forward()" (overridden as "forward(int)" when I need >1 leaps), I just read single bits in groups of arbitrary length starting from a semi-random position on the ring.
And the *ring* not having an end, even if the "leap" ends beyond the last item (or the group of bits crosses it), I just land on the first ones and everything's fine.

So.

I start reading from the first element of the ring.
I collect 4 bits, translate them in a decimal value and "leap forward" by as many items.
At this point I read just 3+3+2 bits, translate them in decimals and use these values for something else.
In the meanwhile, every time I move through the ring I save the current position in a variable, so that the next "read&leap" will start from there and not from the beginning again.

What happens is that after a few rounds, depending on how long the ring is, one of the "->next" addresses goes terribly wrong and inexplicably changes into something like 517f7f7f or 92808080 (yep, they really look that way, with repeated pairs) and the program crashes.

Just to understand what was going wrong, I wrote down quite a number of "cout" that report at what stage of each function the program got and more or less explicitly tell me what's going on, complete with variables' current value and everything.
The very weird thing is that the error happens even during the verbose [do while] loop that nothing does but read nodes' address (it's a cout, thus no "== to =" oversights possible).

So, everything's fine for a few rounds until...."something" happens, one of the addresses in the "next" value of a node changes to a suspiciously perfect looking number and *sbam!*, Windows tells me the program crashed.

Let me know if you need some other details or some chunks of code to better understand the situation.

---

### EDIT 2015-10-20_1645

Here some chunks of code, the ones that create and interact with the list, and part of the output (sorry for the italian language, it shouldn't prevent comprehension of what is happening).

---

### HEADER

```
class girdleNode
{
public:
    girdleNode();
    ~girdleNode();
    void setBit(uchar bitIn){bit = bitIn;}
    uchar getBit(){return bit;}

    friend class keyGirdle;

private:
    girdleNode * next;
    uchar bit;
};


class keyGirdle
{
public:
    keyGirdle(ullong);
    ~keyGirdle();
    void setFirst(girdleNode * pFirst){this->first = pFirst; current = first;}
    void forward();
    void forward(uint);
    void atFirst(){current = first;}
    void atNode(ullong);

private:
    girdleNode * current;
    girdleNode * first;
};
```

---

### CPP

```
keyGirdle::keyGirdle(ullong length)
{
    first = new girdleNode;
    girdleNode * pCursor = first;
    pCursor->setBit(0);

    for (ullong c = 0; c < (length - 1); c++)
    {
        pCursor->next = new girdleNode;
        pCursor = pCursor->next;
        pCursor->setBit(0);
    }

    pCursor->next = first;
    current = first;
}



uchar main_class::leaper(girdleNode * node)
{
    girdleNode * pCursor = node;

    do //this loop exposes the girdle as it is starting with the node provided in the function argument
    {
        std::cout << pCursor << "<->";
        pCursor = pCursor->next;
    }while (pCursor != node); //THIS is the point where addresses go wrong, in the middle of this loop

    pCursor = node; //I assign the starting node again after I moved the cursor

    for (int c = 0; c < 4; c++)
    {
        std::cout << "c= " << c << " << pCursor= " << pCursor << "\n"
                     "pCursor->getBit()= " << (pCursor->getBit() ? "1" : "0") << "\n"
                     "pCursor->next= " << pCursor->next << "\n";

        leapBits[c] = pCursor->getBit();
        pCursor = pCursor->next;

        std::cout << "new pCursor value= " << pCursor << "\n\n";
    }

    return bits2dec(leapBits[0], leapBits[1], leapBits[2], leapBits[3]);
}
```

---

### CORRECT OUTPUT

> `[.....]`
>
> `>> Stage: 302`
>
> `>> Stage: 1702`
>
> `>> Stage: 602`
>
> `>> Stage: 107`
>
> `>> Stage: 2301`
>
> `>> Stage: 2302`
>
> `Esposizione keyGirdle prima della lettura dei leapBits:`
>   `0x732c28<->0x732cb0<->0x732cc0<->0x732cd0<->0x732ce0<->0x732cf0<->0x732d00<->0x7 32d10<->0x732d20<->0x732d30<->0x732d40<->0x732d50<->0x732e78<->0x732e88<->0x736b
>   b8<->0x736be0<->`

---

### ERROR OUTPUT

> `[.....]`
>
> `>> Stage: 302`
>
> `>> Stage: 1702`
>
> `>> Stage: 602`
>
> `>> Stage: 107`
>
> `>> Stage: 2301`
>
> `>> Stage: 2302`
>
> `Esposizione keyGirdle prima della lettura dei leapBits:`
>   `0x732c28<->0x732cb0<->0x51808080<->`

There where you see the nodes list end at just the third address (0x51808080) is where the program breaks and Windows' warning comes up to tell me it stopped working.
The two ouputs are from the same run, they're not result of multiple tests (notice the same addresses in the list).

Comment: Could you post the traversal code? It's difficult to figure out what went wrong just from your description.

Comment: I second what @pablochan mentioned. You need code to understand these kinds of question.

Comment: As the problem is in your code, we certainly need to see the code to help you.

Comment: If you want to try it on your own: I would write a little CheckListHeath function that runs through the list and checks, whether all the next pointers are still healthy. If you are on Windows you might want to use IsBadReadPtr() to check a next pointer before using it in you CheckListHealth function. Call that function in several places of your code and you might get a clue, where the fault happens.

Comment: There you go, added some details.

Comment: The ouput you show was not produced by the code shown. Also the code shown is not a complete compilable example. Wild guess - you call `leaper`with an invalid pointer.

Comment: The output doesnt look like produced by that code because I cut out all the verbose cout's I used to return code stages.
With those lines in you wouldnt understand anything more than what you already have here, because they're just indexes with no meaning.
The part of the output that really matters still has its verbosity in the code I've posted, which is where the program breaks.
I cant post the whole program, there are several functions that dont interact with the girdle, too much code to post in a single thread.
The pointer is valid, otherwise it wouldnt run right a single time.

Comment: I've done some other tests with verbose couts and the girdle's cursor moves just fine for several turns crossing the last/first seam without a single problem; until it gives me one of those weird 0x##808080 addresses in a position inside the girdle that doesnt make any mathematical/topological sense.
Some kind of test I might have not thought of?

Comment: It seems, by logging every single test, that the break always appears after the second node.
The second node's "->next" changes to that strange 808080 value and after that the program crashes.
I'm attentively monitored the girdle's "current" value and it's always correct and all the nodes point to their correct next at every single step of the program.
I cant really understand.....

Comment: I'm rewriting the whole thing from scratch, with a better handling of public/private and accessors to avoid external classes/functions can fiddle with mem addresses and other values.